# Geting entities by id/key without specifying the ancestor key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use go  with app engine and datastore. I have Restaurants and Owners entities. *Owner* is parent to *Restaurant*. I show list of restaurants on main web page. When visitor clicks on a restaurant, the profile page(www.../restaurants/:id) will open. I don't have ancestor key at that point. How should I retrieve the restaurant? I could use /restaurants/:key but datastore.key is quite long string.
What is the natural way of doing this? should I use unique restaurant names and query/filter by that?

Comment: Why have the Owners an Ancestor, Use a relation instead.  ie owner = KeyProperty() in the restaurant.  Are you using  transaction groups involving both owners and restaurants at all? Often people over user the ancestor property for owned relationships and then suffer the downsides.  For instance if your restaurant changes it's owner you have to recreate the restaurant with a new parent.  If you access to the restaurant doesn't always involve the owner you have your issue.  What benefit do you currently get by using the owner as the ancestor ?

Comment: Is KeyProperty a term in Python? I use Go. So, I use Ancestor because when I delete the owner, I may want to delete restaurants under it, then delete menus under restaurants and so on. Sounds like I need transactions. I don't know how to do it smart way. 
But do you mean I add a string field under Restaurant and set it's value to Owner's key value? If so, I can do it.

Comment: KeyProperty is the same as `Datastore key` in go.  There is no cascading deletes even if you use an ancestor.   So you have to perform a series of queries and deletes. Yes a single transaction could  be appropriate but you have XG transactions so its not that a big deal.  Is it worth complicating your most common requirement finding restaurants when you don't know the parent with out a query, vs the occasional deletion of a owner ?  Thats something you have decide about.  Look at all your general use cases and design the data model to support efficiently the most common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your current data model (restaurants child entities of owners). All you need is to add "Owner" variable to a restaurant.

When you retrieve restaurant entity, you can extract owner ID from its key - every key already includes a parent key, if any. In Java it looks like this:

```
restaurant.setOwner(entity.getParent().getId());
```

When you need to get/save the restaurant entity, you can create its full key using its own identifier and a parent key, created with owner ID.